# How to detect if Google account hasn't Gmail

Tags: gmail-api

How can I recognize Google accounts without Gmail?

I use OAuth2 for authorization and then download user messages.
But if Google account hasn't Gmail, then I receive the error while getting data from api:
    {
        "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "failedPrecondition",
            "message": "Bad Request"
        }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Bad Request"
    }

What is the best way to detect accounts without Gmail?
Now I just send test GET request to gmail-api and check that it returns OK.
But I'm looking for best solution.

Comment: I think you've got it. You could wrap that call into a CheckGmailAccount() function that returns a boolean to hide the details from classes that don't need to know how to interpret that response.